# Nginx - location redirective

Tags: nginx

I am trying below config but its not working as expected.

I do have index.html page under /book directory (/usr/share/nginx/html/book) and I need to access it from let say when I access localhost:8080/book it should show index.html under book directory.

its working when I try localhost:8080/book/ but not working for localhost:8080/book (without trailing slash '/'). can you please let me know where I went wrong. Thanks!

default.conf:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;
    

    location = /book {
     root /usr/share/nginx/html;
     index index.html;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you mapping port 8080 to port 80. Normally, `/book` will redirect to `/book/` before processing the `index` directive. But the port change will cause that process to fail.

Comment: You could try: `location = /book { return 301 http://$http_host/book/; }`